# Problem while Implemented :active in CSS Button

Tags: html, css

I have problem while make menu using CSS. The problem is I would like to use :active to make my current button highlighted. But after tried so many times, I still can't find how to implement it in my code.

I use `<li>` tag inside `<a>` tag to make sure the button background and text color change while selected, because after tried to put `<a>` tag outside `<li>` tag the text color not changed when select the button, the text only change after I put the cursor into the text.

Need your help.

This is my CSS code:

```
a, body {
    margin-top:-30px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#topmenu {
    margin-left:170px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#topmenu li {
    color:white;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    padding:20px 15px 10px 15px;;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 1px grey;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px grey;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px grey;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #2F2727, #004890);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#004890), to(#2F2727));
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #555;
}

#topmenu li:hover, #topmenu li:active
{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #FED93A, #FEC13A);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FEC13A), to(#FED93A));
    color:black;
    padding-top:30px;
}

#topmenu #home {
    margin-right:10px;
}

#topmenu #logout {
    background:#000;
    color:white;
}
```

and this my HTML code:

```
<div id="topmenu">
 <ul>
  <img src="includes/menu/pics.gif" alt="" style="float:left;"/>
  <a href="../folder/home.php"><li id="home">Home</li></a>
  <a href="../folder/A.php"><li>A</li></a>
  <a href="../folder/B.php"><li>B</li></a>
  <a href="../folder/C.php"><li>C</li></a>
  <a href="../"><li id="logout">Logout</li></a>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to make sure - are you sure you fully understand how :active works? And your code sample does not have :active defined.

Comment: @easwee
Sorry for not put my :active in my question, I already fix it. I have put in with #topmenu li:hover, but it cannot work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Thank you all, look like I don't fully understand about :active pseudo-classes. I want to make my menu like http://jasamarga.co.id/bmmr top menu. While I choose "Kontak Kami", background of the button change into blue.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the point mates. The :active pseudo class does not work like this.

[:active sitepoint CSS reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-active)

> This pseudo-class matches any element that’s in the process of being activated. It would apply, for instance, for the duration of a mouse-click on a link, from the point at which the mouse button’s pressed down until the point at which it’s released again. The pseudo-class does not signify a link to the active, or current, page—that’s a common misconception among CSS beginners

What he wants to acheive is apply styles to the current a which has nothing to do with the above "active pseudo-class".

There are many ways you could acheive this.

[First](http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/highlighting-current-page-with-css)

[Second](http://www.mstudiostalk.com/2008/03/11/pure-css-to-display-the-active-page-in-the-navigation/)

[Third](http://www.search-this.com/2007/06/13/css-current-page-indicator/)

[Fourth](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/roll11.htm)

Comment: I want to make my list like this

Comment: Sorry for uncompleted comment, I just want to make my active button appears like when I hover it.

Comment: Sorry mate. I am confused what you want to do. Do you want to (1)Apply some styles to the "a" or "li" when it is active and by active you mean the user has clicked that "a" in the navigation and is currently being displayed? Or (2) apply some styles when the user hovers over the "a" or "li" with his mouse be it that it is "active" or not?

Comment: Have you try my code? I already clear my goal, to make the selected button appears like when I hover it. Please try it first.

Comment: Sorry look like I don't fully understand about :active. Thanks for your comments :) I really appreciate it.

Comment: Mate I did try you code. You are not very helpful. Here is the fiddle. Tell me where the problem is and what you want http://jsfiddle.net/jDtQY/

Comment: I want to make my menu look like this site http://jasamarga.co.id/bmmr top menu. While I choose "Kontak Kami" the background of "Kontak Kami" button change into blue.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what the above 4 links will teach you how to do. You want the background of the current/active tab to be blue which is done by many methods and one of the them is using CSS by either giving the a element class of active or current and than applying styles to it or by giving the body an id and than applying styles to it. Look at the code of the site "<li class="active item23" id="current">". In your li#home give it a class of "active" and use li.active {background-color: blue;} in your first page. In the second page give the <li>A</li> the active class and remove from home

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that :active doesn't mean what you think it does.

:active triggers when you click on an element, but before you let up on the mouse button. See the [CSS spec on dynamic pseudo classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes).

Here's an example HTML page, with :active on both the `<a>` and `<h1>` elements, you'll see the text color changes to blue when you click and hold down the mouse button.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      a, h1 { color: red; }
      a:active, h1:active { color: blue; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>headline</h1>
    <a href="#">link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: p.s. Your HTML is also invalid. You must do `<li><a>link</a></li>`, not `<a><li>link</li></a>`. You cannot nest elements inside a `<ul>` except for other list elements. The browser will implicitly insert an `<li>` before the `<img>` tag and break things. Paste your HTML fragment into the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org) and you will see. You should re-nest your elements like this: `<div><img /><ul><li><a /></li></ul></div>`. Always start with valid HTML first, before you start debugging CSS!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to have the links inside the li items, like this:

```
<li><a href="../folder/A.php">A</a></li>
```

That's the proper way of nesting them. Then you want to give the active list item a class="active" atribute and set the css styles for it that you want.

Comment: I already try but the problem is while I select the button, only the background changed but the text color not changed. The text color `<a>` tag only changed while I put my pointer in text.

Comment: then change your css accordingly? I'm sorry but I don't know of a sandbox I could use to help you out. Also, what do you want to happen when the link is active?

Comment: I just want to make my active link appears like hover.
I already fix the code, I put the #topmenu li:active beside #topmenu li:hover.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that issue too. So what I did is I added a class into the

. For example in your case, I would have done this:

(1)Add a class named active in your HTML code as the first step.

```
<div class="topmenu">

 <ul>
  <img src="includes/menu/pics.gif" alt="" style="float:left;"/>
  <a class="active" href="../folder/home.php"><li id="home">Home</li></a>
  <a href="../folder/A.php"><li>A</li></a>
  <a href="../folder/B.php"><li>B</li></a>``
  <a href="../folder/C.php"><li>C</li></a>
  <a href="../"><li id="logout">Logout</li></a>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Secondly, what I did is I went to my CSS code and I would type in :

```
     div.topmenu ul.active {`
`background-color:black;
 color:white;
}
```

It worked for me. Hopefully, it helps you. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

I'm *fairly* certain that `:active` only triggers on links (`A` tags). It doesn't (and shouldn't) work on arbitrary elements like `LI`.

I think there may be a way for you to work around this. Have you tried keeping *structural* properties (float, margin, etc.) on the LIs, but moving the *visual* properties (border, padding, colors, etc.) to the As? That way, you can just style `#topmenu li a:hover`, `#topmenu li a:active`, and so on.

Comment: Nothing in the standard limits the elements that `:active` applies to.

Comment: Incorrect. There is no such limitation as being only applicable to anchor tags. I use it on almost everything.