# Can't seem to change color of link

Tags: css

Here's a screenshot of the problem:
[image]

Notice that we're on the `stalk` page. The CSS I wrote is supposed to change the color of the active page. Here is the CSS:

```
#nav {
    border-top:10px solid #A7C1D1;
    height:45px;
    padding-left:100px;
    padding-top:20px;
    margin-left:0;
    color:#000;
}

  #nav a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  #nav a:visited {
    color:#000;
  }

  #nav a:hover {
    color:#93AFBF;
  }

  #nav .active {
    color:#93AFBF;
  }
```

Before, I had the CSS for `#nav .active` to create a border around the active page. This worked and I could see the border around the word "stalk" when I was on the /stalk page. But this time around, I decided to just change the color of the word. This is where I ran into the issue.

Here is the HTML rendered for the page:

```
  <div id="nav"> 
    <a href="/">home</a> &middot; <a href="/stalk" class="active">stalk</a> &middot; <a href="#">link3</a> &middot; <a href="#">link4</a> 
  </div>
```

If I take away the CSS for `#nav a:visited` then the CSS for `#nav .active` works, but now the visited links are blue when I want them to stay black.

Comment: This code doesn't seem to have any problem with it: http://jsfiddle.net/hFnHZ/ The `stalk` hyperlink changes color... I'm using Chrome 11.0.696.68

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
#nav a.active {
    color:#93AFBF;
  }
```

The `#nav a:visited` has higher [specificity <sup>w3 specs</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) than `#nav .active` and thus gets applied.

Comment: How does `#nav a:visited` have a higher specificity than `#nav .active`? The first is `0,1,0,2` and the second is `0,1,1,0`, no?

Comment: @Richard: `#nav a:visited` specifies an ID and an element with a pseudo-class, which inherently increases it's specificity compared to targeting an ID containing a class.

Comment: @Jawad It's .active (that is a class with the name "active") not :active (a pseudo class). It is an uninspired name for a class, but the solution is correct

Comment: @Richard, i believe it is first:`0,1,1,1` vs second:`0,1,1,0`. Because pseudo classes are in the third counter. Try the http://www.suzyit.com/tools/specificity.php

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli - Ah, yes; I'm confusing pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements.

Comment: @sica07 What's a more creative way to highlight the active controller?

Comment: @Rachel I didn't thought of any other way, I'm ok with this. In fact I'm not sure if I understand your question. If it's related to my answer about the "uninspired name for a class", then I think that you got me wrong. I was just saying that you could use some other name for the active controller (link) class; anything but "active", because there is also the active pseudo class, and also, in CSS, an active link is not what  most will think of, see Jawad answer and the Site Point Reference info about this topic

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
#nav a.active
{
   color: #93afbf
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#nav a:link {color: #000;}
#nav a:visited {color: #000;}
#nav a:hover {color: #93afbf;}
#nav a:active {color: #93afbf;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the active pseudo class

[Site Point Refrence](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-active)

> This pseudo-class matches any element that’s in the process of being activated. It would apply, for instance, for the duration of a mouse-click on a link, from the point at which the mouse button’s pressed down until the point at which it’s released again. The pseudo-class does not signify a link to the active, or current, page—that’s a common misconception among CSS beginners.

[Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055987/problem-while-implemented-active-in-css-button/6056377#6056377)

Comment: he is not confusing anything .. look at his markup.. he has manually added the `active` class to the link he wants..

Comment: @Jawad - Where is the `:active` pseudo-class in this question? So far it is only in answers.

Comment: So my answer (which has now been voted down) was correct all along?

Comment: Mate! I did not vote down your answer. If others have voted down your answer because of my comments, I am sorry. Guess they are as stupid as me!

Comment: @Steve, for what it is worth, i upvoted your answer since it was correct and faster than mine, but then proceeded and answered as well with some explanations as well...

Comment: No worries man, I'm not worried about the votes to be honest, I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't talking nonsense in the first place :)

Comment: Thanks Gaby. Will be carefull next time. I deserve a votedown. Heck I deserve 100 votes down.

Answer (score 0):

Border property is not inherited while color property it is. So you inherit the color property for your link from the #nav, while the border property was the one declared in the "active" class rules. You should declare the color property for the link with the "active" class as suggested by Gaby

Answer (score 0):

Tonight I found an unusual one. (A link color that I couldn't change.) I went into the inspector and first found the `text-decoration-color` property set. But no, that would be too easy. I scroll down to `color` and find this `:not` selector, which a theme author created. In my specific case, the solution was to duplicate (overwrite) this weird selector with the color I wanted:

`#the-post .entry-content a:not(.shortc-button) { 
    color: white !important;
}`

My suggestion is to go into your inspector (F12) and find the "Computed" tab and look where the colors are coming from. Usually it's straightforward where the color is coming from, and the inspector will even tell you which file and which line number set the color. Then the decision is, do you have access/permission to that file? Or maybe you have access, but do you necessarily want access to that file?

If you want to avoid changing the source of the color, for whatever reason, you can just re-declare the color again further down the page, like in your footer, or immediately after the theme is loaded, whatever the case may be. Of course given the option, it's usually preferable to find the root of the problem and then you end up using less CSS code which loads faster and is easier to maintain.