# making <button> respond to :active, is it even possible

Tags: html, css

So far it only responds to hover, no clue why it doesn't respond to active

Here is the fidddle http://jsfiddle.net/tP9E9/1/.

CSS:

```
.menu ul li button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(206,0,0,1);
}

.menu ul li button:active {
    background-color: rgba(206,0,0,1);
}
```

As you can probably guess, I have couple of divs with various content that open in response to button clicks. Hover works fine, but when div corresponding to button is opened (active) the button doesn't go red. Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem while Implemented :active in CSS Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055987/problem-while-implemented-active-in-css-button)

Comment: It does for me. You're specifying the same color for both `:hover` and `:active` states, though...

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
<input type="button" value="news">
```

and css

```
input:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
input:active {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

You can also add **:focus** which will be available on Tab.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/menian/tP9E9/3/)